# Sum a column range in a table from loop variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use this logic:

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
```

In a loop string. Right now the data is create by the loop, so I'm attempting to select the row above, and all the rows for the table for that column, and add the SUM to the cell below.

I'm using a loop as the table can change depending on the reference, and when the data is received I add a new table. Everything works good up to when I want to sum a column in the table and add it below. The cell always returns a 0.

At this point

```
i = 6
j = 13

ws2.Cells(i , j ).Value = Application.Sum _
    (Range(Cells(i, j - 1), Cells(i, j - 1).End(xlUp)))
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is a technique using `WorksheetFunction.Sum` to create a running total.

```
Sub AddRunningTotal()

    Const FIRST_ROW = 2
    Const SOURCE_COLUMN = 11

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, SOURCE_COLUMN), .Cells(.Rows.Count, SOURCE_COLUMN).End(xlUp))
            .Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C[-1]:RC[-1])"
            'Uncomment to replace the formulas with their values
            '.Value = Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help on this.